# ASP.NET 5.0 and Identity 3.0 with MongoDB in Azure

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have implemented a custom Identity 3.0 provider with MongoDB. It's working fine in localhost, but when I upload it to Azure, I have this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
>   MongoDB.Driver.FindOptionsBase.set_AllowPartialResults(Boolean)'.
>   MyProject.Web.Identity.UserStore`3.FindByNameAsync(String
>   normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

**RAW Details Error:**

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void MongoDB.Driver.FindOptionsBase.set_AllowPartialResults(Boolean)'.
   at MyProject.Web.Identity.UserStore`3.FindByNameAsync(String normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.SignInManager`1.d__31.MoveNext()

Method throwing the error in UserStore.cs:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Finds and returns a user, if any, who has the specified normalized user name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="normalizedUserName">The normalized user name to search for.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="CancellationToken"/> used to propagate notifications that the operation should be cancelled.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The <see cref="Task"/> that represents the asynchronous operation, containing the user matching the specified User if it exists.
        /// </returns>
        public virtual Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(normalizedUserName)) return Task.FromResult((TUser)null);

            var filter = Builders<TUser>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Email, Normalize(normalizedUserName));
            var options = new FindOptions { AllowPartialResults = false };

            return DatabaseContext.UserCollection.Find(filter, options).SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

I have tested in localhost connecting to "production database", and I don't have this error, and all works fine.

I'm using MongoDb Driver C# 2.1.1.

Why works in Localhost and not in Azure? What happens if a remove the AllowPartialResults?

Thanks.